# Where NOT IN () on a join?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following scope in a Rails model.

```
class Suggestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favourites

  def self.favoured_by(user)
    joins(:favourites).where(favourites: { user_id: user.id })
  end
end
```

That works perfectly. It will return all the suggestions which a particular user has favourited.

How can I retrieve all the suggestions which are either not favourited at all or which are favourited but not by this particular user?

```
def self.not_favoured_by(user)
  # ...
end
```

My `Favourite` model looks like this:

```
class Favourite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :suggestion
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Could you also post your `favourite` model?

Comment: Why you don't make a relation has_many trough instead of that join?

Comment: @ismaelga @PaulSimpson I added my `Favourite` model to the OP. `Favourite` needs to be a join model between `User` and `Suggestion` because user's can favourite suggestions which belong to other users.

Comment: ActiveRecord does that for you. You can do in User `has_many :suggestions, :through => :favorites`. Since you already should have a suggestions relation in User you must change to something like favorited_suggestions, but I don't have time now to find out how to do that. And you could the save at Suggestions to have something like users_favorited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
favorited_suggestions_ids = joins(:favourites).where(favourites: { user_id: user.id }).map(&:id)
return scoped if favorited_suggestion_ids.empty?
where('id not in (?)',favorited_suggestions_ids)
```

Comment: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: id: SELECT "suggestions".* FROM "suggestions" INNER JOIN "favourites" ON "favourites"."suggestion_id" = "suggestions"."id" WHERE (id not in (2)) ORDER BY created_at DESC`. My first thought was to prefix `id` with `suggestions` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You did `suggestion_id not in (?)` and `.map(&:suggestion_id)`? I was not sure what was the id

Comment: Actually I think you don't need the join in the second query, because you don't need the favorites there. Edited my answer. Problem should be solved. The error was because in that join there was suggestions.id and favourites.id, so by ambiguous it means there is more than one id to pick

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def self.not_favoured_by(user)
  sql = <<-SQL
    SELECT suggestions.* FROM suggestions 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
      (SELECT id FROM favourites WHERE user_id = #{user.id} AND favourites.suggestion_id = suggestions.id);
  SQL
  find_by_sql(sql)
end
```

Comment: While this version does work I prefer the non-raw-SQL version so that's why I am accepting that one.